How to upload file and json with SpringBoot and dio?
I have a controller which needs a multipart file and an User object as paramters:
@PostMapping("/user")
public String uploadUser(@RequestPart("file")MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("user") User user){
    log.info(user.toString());
    return "success";
}

User defined below:
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public User(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Now I want to use dio with Flutter on ios 17.4 platform
uploadFile() async {
    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename: 'dog.png'),
      'user': {'id': 123, 'name': 'abc'}
    });
    try {
      var response = await dio.post('$baseUrl/user', data: formData);
      log.i(response);
    } catch (e) {
      log.e(e);
    }
  }

But spring boot reports Required part 'user' is not present, the whole message is Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required part 'user' is not present.]
I tried using jsonEncode like this but it didn't work:
Map<String, dynamic> user = {
      'id':123,
      'name':'abc'
    };
    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename: 'dog.png'),
      'user': jsonEncode(user)
    });

It says Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported .
I found it works on postman when updating user as a json file but when I tried uploading file with dio like this:
var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename: 'dog.png'),
      'user': await MultipartFile.fromFile(jsonPath, filename: 'user.json')
    });

it still says Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported.
How can I fix it?

This works for me, hope it works for you, too.
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.FilePart;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;

@PostMapping(value = "/user", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public String uploadUser(
            @RequestPart("file") FilePart file,
            @RequestPart("user") User user
    ){
        log.info(user.toString());
        return "success";
    }

